# Prestashop module RenderView in backOffice Controller

Tags: php, controller, prestashop, smarty

I am developing a module for Prestashop, and came the moment when I need a new controller.

I created it, no problem, but now that I want to display some infos in it, there's the problems appears.

I have this very basic code :

```
class PingdomProbeAdminController extends ModuleAdminController 
{
  public $name = "ProbeAdmin";

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->bootstrap = true;
    $this->display = 'view';
    $this->meta_title = $this->l('Create your new Probe');
    $this->module = 'pingdom';
    parent::__construct();
    if (!$this->module->active)
        Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminHome'));
  }

  public function renderView()
  {
    $this->tpl_view_vars = array(

    );
    $this->base_tpl_view = 'probeAdmin.tpl';
    parent::renderView();
  }
}
```

And I obviously have `probeAdmin.tpl` located at `modules/pingdom/views/templates/admin/pingdom/helpers/view/probeAdmin.tpl`

But Smarty still complaining with `Unable to load template file 'helpers/view/probeAdmin.tpl'`...

Thant you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify version but anyway:

1. Your controller class name is wrong, it should be `AdminPingdomProbeController` and filename should have the same name `AdminPingdomProbeController.php`
2. The folder where you put your template file is incorrect it should be in `modules/pingdom/views/templates/admin/pingdom_probe/helpers/view/probeAdmin.tpl`.

If you have camelcased controller name between `Admin` and `Controller` your template folder needs to be lowercased and camelcases replaced with underscore.

**Edit:**

You are also missing `return` in your `renderView` method.

```
return parent::renderView();
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a doc where I could find detailed instructions to create a BO module's controller ? 

I do have made the modifications but the only result was the new page wasn't found...

Plus I have imitated another module's Controller I have found installed, called `gamification` and this one is working well...

Comment: @BorisLeMéec Did you reinstall your module and correct the controller name in tab installation?

Comment: Not yet, but I'd like to see an official place where I can find these infos... I very dislike doing stuff not knowing why :/

Comment: @BorisLeMéec Well then you're going to be looking for a long time, since official documentation is poor. Also I don't know how you imitated `gamification` controller since it follows naming convention I wrote in the answer https://github.com/PrestaShop/gamification/blob/master/controllers/admin/AdminGamificationController.php

Comment: Ok, so I have done all your modification. Seems to work but.
I can load the controller, and if I change `$this->base_tpl_view = 'probe_admin.tpl';` to an non existing file name, it doesn't work. Seems logic. But in my `probe_admin.tpl` nothing is displaying.

Comment: @BorisLeMéec Because you are missing `return` in your method `return parent::renderView();`.